# How do I maintain a consistent Ubuntu environment across multiple VM's?

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management

I'm looking for a solution to maintaining package versions across multiple Ubuntu environments.

I have multiple machines in different geographical locations and are not on WAN. Some don't even have an internet connection. I deploy custom software to these machines, but I test against the latest packages before physically going to each site to deploy this software.

Quite often by the time I get to install the tested software some packages have been updated, so when I do a `apt-get upgrade` or `apt-get dist-upgrade` the packages are not the same as the test environment.

So how do I ensure that my Ubuntu installs are all running the same packages?